# Gigabyte P34Wv4-BW1T Ubuntu 15.10 no audio from speakers

Tags: sound, 15.10

I'm trying to get Ubuntu working on my new laptop. I'm having a few problems and I'm very frustrated. 
The first problem (I will ask different questions for the others):
I'm not able to hear sound from my speakers. I am able to hear sound through my headphone jack, though.

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

```
my@my-P34V4:~$ ^C

my@my-P34V4:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a456
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
    Memory at 9bd14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cb1 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
--
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 8ca0
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a456
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at 9bd10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c90 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

I went into the alsamixer and unmuted what I could. That didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line, go into alsamixer   and unmute everything ("00")
Be sure to select Auto-Mute Mod and then Disabled.

You might have to press the unmute button  FN+ if one exists.